# MVVM WPF - Changing Views creates new Instances of View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've decided to move away from WinForms as I wanted to be more flexible in creating my UIs. That said I'm just starting with WPF and the MVVM structure. I'm having a blast learning all the new stuff and trying to learn the "best practices" right away.

One thing I'm wondering is that with my current implementation of MVVM and navigation through my views it would always create a new instance of the View when changing my `CurrentView` of my `MainViewModel` of my `MainWindow`.

**Is that the intended way? As I notice quite a bit of lagging when changing them which feels ... wrong?** As a sidenote I'm currently not on my normal workstation but on a older surface which is getting stressed easily with VS running etc

A pretty 'standard' MainViewModel

```
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.PageViewModels.Add(new EventsViewModel());
            this.PageViewModels.Add(new SettingsViewModel());
            this.PageViewModels.Add(new AnotherViewModel());

            this.CurrentView = this.PageViewModels[0];
        }

        public ViewModelBase CurrentView
        {
            get
            {
                return this._currentVIew;
            }

            set
            {
                this._currentVIew = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }


        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    this.changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => this.ChangeViewModel(p),
                        p => true);
                }

                return this.changePageCommand;
            }
        }

        private void ChangeViewModel(object viewModel)
        {
            var t = (Type)viewModel;
            foreach (var v in this.PageViewModels)
            {
                if (v.GetType() == t)
                {
                    this.CurrentView = v;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

'Normal' View Data Templating

```
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:EventsViewModel}">
                <view:EventView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:AnotherViewModel}">
                <view:AnotherView/>
            </DataTemplate>
```

The way the Command is beeing called, just with different `x:Type` parameter

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
CommandParameter="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}"
```

Comment: It's usual to create a new templated view each time, because you want to reset to a known state.  Do your views do anything much in their ctor? Are they very complicated? Have you tried compiling, closing vs down and just running the exe?

Comment: But this also means swapping views will discard all text etc put in a textbox etc. Would I want to not go with a traditional MVVM in that case?

I did create some controls in the ctor as I only know about them by runtime. Basically loading entries from file/adding new ones/saving them which results in additional custom controls beeing created and displayed

I just want to make sure I'm using the 'best practice' for my usecase. If that is how its done I would probably go with it or create some custom way by using a singleton for the view or similar.

Comment: It's entirely usual to wish to complete edits and persist changes before you navigate to some other view.  You should do as little as possible in your view ctor. Doesn't sound like you're following best practice with whatever this loading entries from files is.

Comment: Its not implemented yet. But not sure how you would go about it.
It would load a file containing X sets of data. Each set needs to be shown in my view as a usercontrol. The data is available at the time of creating the UI, so when creating the view the usercontrols need to be created.

Or how would you handle that?

Comment: Viewmodel first. Always. Asynchronously load your data in a task in your viewmodel. Which can contain collections of other viewmodels, properties which are viewmodels. Get the idea?

Comment: Yea totally get it! Will keep it in mind when adding that stuff!